# is there a way to configure spring cloud aws with aws clientconfiguration information when connecting through proxy

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is there a way to Set optional proxy details on  `com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration`  connecting through a proxy,
am developing with `spring-cloud-aws-version 1.0.0.RELEASE`, `spring-boot-version 1.2.2.RELEASE` in `spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure`.  I want to be able to configure proxy details as follows

```
setProxyHost(java.lang.String proxyHost)
setProxyPassword(java.lang.String proxyPassword)
setProxyPort(int proxyPort)
setProxyUsername(java.lang.String proxyUsername)
```

cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey and cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey is set in a `application.properties`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was answered in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/63).

Summary: there is currently no way to specify a custom client configuration. Instead a custom client must be configured and provided. This can be done with java config as well as with XML:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();        
    factory.setAmazonSqs(customAmazonClient);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(customAmazonClient);

    return factory;
}
```

Or XML:

```
<aws-messaging:annotation-driven-queue-listener amazon-sqs="customAmazonClient" send-to-message-template="messageTemplateThatUsers CustomAmazonClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped with setting the deleteMessageOnException property to false so that message are not deleted if there is an exception, but not a redrive policy.